# Event handler handling events out of order

Tags: c#, events, timer, bluetooth-lowenergy, eventhandler

I'm doing some work with a radio microcontroller (BLE). The mechanism supported in .NET's `GenericAttributeProfile` namespace, is to use an `EventHandler` whenever new data comes in (notifications).  A problem I'm currently seeing is that, despite my data being sent in order from the radio hardware, the data does not necessarily get dealt with in that order. I'm guessing this is due to the asynchronous manner in which the `EventHandler` is invoked (please correct me if I'm wrong). Every time a new piece of data comes in, the event handler is invoked, which then reads the data, and writes to console the data and a static variable which increments every time the event handler is called (not thread safe, but seems to be OK for testing). The data it is printing out if also incrementing, and I can see that the events are being handled out of order.

So my question is, **how do I ensure that events are handled in order**. From the research I've done, I can only find literature on the order of eventHandler execution. I don't care about that here as I only have 1 eventHandler. I care about the order of event execution

Comment: Do you have control tocthe defined event or are you using a builtin event and only creating am eventhandler?

Comment: I am using GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged (from the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile namespace). It should fire every time a notification is received from the radio. I have simply subscribed to the event GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged += MyEventHandler.

Comment: You shouldnt count on the execution order of eventhandlers in your code. If you do, you should rethink your design

Comment: There is ambiguity here, so let's clarify what you're saying. I could have multiple event handlers (i.e. subscribe more than one method to the GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged, e.g. GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged += eventHandler1, GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged += eventHandler2). I know when an event is invoked eventHandler1 or 2 could complete in any arbitrary order. The second case is that an event causes an event handler to be invoked, and if events come quick enough can cause eventHandlers to queue up. When evenHandlers are served, they are done in any order

Comment: . Please clarify that you mean, when an event occurs, if the events are fast enough, the order in which the events are dealt with (through calling the eventhandlers), can be in any order.

Comment: EventHandlers will probably be invoked in the order in which thet were added. But you cannot rely on that when you write your code. For example, if my events `add` and `remove` methods save the delegate being passed in a stack liked fasion (last in, first out)

Comment: That wasn't the clarification I was after - the ambiguity still exists. I only have one EventHandler, but many events. Are you saying that each event creates one EventHandler, and that EventHandler can be in any order, therefore an events can be handled in any order. So if I have 5 events come in, does that create 5 EventHandlers, which could be invoked in any order?

Comment: If you suspect a bug in the platform, it will require troubleshooting efforts [such as these](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ujjwalk/archive/2014/07/17/a-tale-of-few-bytes-btle-based-iot-device-with-windows-phone-8-1.aspx) to sort out the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 09/15/2014**

I just wanted to let everyone know that I actually had 2 issue going on.  I had originally thought that it had to do with thread timing but that was only part of the problem (for me anyway).  After I fixed my thread timing issue I found out, as the original poster had stated, the events are in fact coming in out of order.  I have confirmed this issue with Microsoft and they are now working on a fix.  As soon as I get a resolution from them I will post it here.

**UPDATE 01/08/2015**

Microsoft has finally reached out to me and has confirmed the issue.  However, they determined that the cost to benefit was too high to add to the 8.1 core so they won't introduce a fix until the next major release of windows.

Comment: The issue he's having is that the events are being fired out of order, or at least they're being fired closely enough that the code in the handlers are executing out of order.  This doesn't resolve that.  This code can still result in the items being out of order.

Comment: Nothing about the lock in any way prevents a reordering of the objects in the manor described.  If you think that it does, then the downvote is that much more important as you clearly need to learn that this *doesn't* solve the problem.

Comment: marked Robby's update as answer. For all future readers, it *seems* that notifications events are not handled in the order they are created, and there doesn't seem to be a fix. However, I never tested this for lower throughput applications (was running the BLE chip with a CI of < 15ms), so maybe it shouldn't really matter much for the use case of BLE (which is low throughput applications).