# Android BLE Streaming

Tags: android, streaming, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to know if it is possibile to implement an Android application that can get data from a BLE device throught BLE Bluetooth streaming.

I'm building an app that read data of a BLE Device but it not implemente streaming. Throught BLE it is possibile to implement a BLE Streaming ?

And if it is possible to implement it, how many data can I downlaod of it ? What is the rate ?

Comment: According to this, streaming (packet pipelines) are possible with one-way messaging.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151579/schemes-for-streaming-data-with-ble-gatt-characteristics

Answer (score 1):

Maximum theoretical throughput is approximately 1400kbps, but a more realistic goal in a real world application is 700kbps.

The concept of streaming is really just numbers transmitted through a medium where the medium is agnostic to what the numbers represent. This is also the case of BLE whose maximum amount of symbols(bits) per second is 2000kbps, but because of overhead in the protocol(preamble, address, header, payload, and error corrections) the maximum amount of numbers transmitted is limited to 1400 kbps (the payloads). BLE does not 'care' what your payload contains.