# Is there a way to send large chunk of data over BLE in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I'm trying to send an image (15000 byte) to a BLE peripheral.

After searching I only found `p5.ble.js` library that supports BLE in JavaScript.

```
function setup() {
    myBLE = new p5ble();

    // Create a 'Write' button
    const writeButton = createButton('Write');
    // writeButton.position(input.x + input.width + 15, 100);
    writeButton.mousePressed(writeToBle);

    for(let i = 0; i < 15000; i++)
    {
      img[i] = i;
      // console.log(img[i]);
    }
}


function writeToBle() {
  var str1 = new TextDecoder().decode(img.slice(0,127));

  // sending 2nd chunk
setTimeout(function(){
    var str2 = new TextDecoder().decode(img.slice(128,255)); // this just result in garbage
      myBLE.write(myCharacteristic, str2);
    }, 1000);

    // sending first chunk
    myBLE.write(myCharacteristic, str1);
    // myBLE.write(myCharacteristic, img.slice(0,127)); // this doesn't send
}
```

This is my first JavaScript code (and it is just a modification of an example code from p5 ble).

With this code I can send `str1` without any problems. I receive the right data and the right number of bytes.

But for some reason when sending `str2` I receive around 500 bytes instead of 128 bytes and the data is just a repetition of these numbers `239, 191, 189`!

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that asking for recommendations for libraries is specifically off topic. If you take that question off, what remains is on topic for the site.

Comment: Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151579/schemes-for-streaming-data-with-ble-gatt-characteristics/37227866#37227866

Answer (score 0):

In BLE communication, data writing and reading operations are determined according to the MTU value. The MTU determined by both parties must be the same so that the communication is healthy and there is no data loss.

I haven't used the library before, but if you review the documentation it will help you set the MTU value.

Coming to your question in the title. Although the maximum with BLE varies depending on the Bluetooth version; You can use a value between minimum 23 and maximum 512.

If you divide your image data into an array according to the MTU size, you can send the array directly over BLE with a for loop.

As Nipo reminds us of an important information,

Do not forget to subtract the 3-byte command (Opcode, Att index) that is part of the MTU from the MTU size you will set.

example
185(MTU)-3 = 182

The array size in which you keep the bytes should be 182.

Example;

```
 function Update(dataURI) {
  RNFS.readFile(filePath, 'base64')
  .then(async contents => {
    const bufArray: any[] = [];

    let data = convertDataURIToBinary(contents);

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += MTU) {
      const outerChunk = data.slice(i, i + MTU);
      bufArray.push(Object.values(outerChunk));
    }

    bufArray.push([194]); // Add last byte stop byte.

    wait(1000).then(() => {
      writePeripheral([193]); // Start byte.
      wait(2000).then(() => {
        for (const bytes of bufArray) {
          writePeripheral(bytes);
        }
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
 }

 function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
  var raw = atob(dataURI);
  var rawLength = raw.length;
  var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

  for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
    array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return array;
 }
```

Comment: There is a 3-byte command (Opcode, Att index) that is part of MTU. You should chunk by MTU - 3 bytes for this to work correctly.

Comment: @Nipo Hello, you are right, I forgot to add. Thank you for the information